# Save Image File for Thermal Camera

Tags: c#, image, save, jpeg

I have inherited some code for an thermal camera and the code is for a demo application. I need to be able to save the images that the camera takes so I can do analysis on it. So far the code only opens a window to preview the cameras video.

```
// get the bitmap and thermography image. The binary image buffer is set to 0(null) because we are not going to use it
seekRet = Seekware_GetImage(mHandle, IntPtr.Zero, thermImageHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), displayBufferHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
if (seekRet == SwReturnCode.None)
{
    // Create bitmap from RGBA data
    bitmap = new Bitmap(ImageWidth, ImageHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    BitmapData bmData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    IntPtr pNative = bmData.Scan0;
    Marshal.Copy(displayBuffer, 0, pNative, (bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height * 4));
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bmData);

}
```

In this function I have tried to add this following line

```
// I added the following 
bitmap.Save("C:\\Tester\\My_Image.jpeg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

If anyone has an ideas on how I should write this to eliminate this error:  **An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll**
That would be awsome, need to figure this out for research.

Comment: Call `.ToString()` on the exception if it is being written to a output  or click [copy exception detail to clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/) if this is in the debugger. We need the details included in that to help you.

Comment: Also, have you considered trying to use [`Image.FromHbitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromhbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of trying to copy over all the bits from a pinned object?

Comment: Does the preview actually work? Where does it show the image?